# "With" statement in Python with multiple files to handle

Tags: python

How do i use the [with](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement in this case?

```
f_spam = open(spam,'r')
f_bar = open(eggs,'r')
...
do something with these files
...
f_spam.close()
f_bar.close()
```

Files number could be greater than two.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also do:

```
from contextlib import nested

with nested(open(spam), open(eggs)) as (f_spam, f_eggs):
    # do something
```

In Python 2.7 and 3.1+ you don't need the `nested` function because `with` supports the following syntax:

```
with open(spam) as f_spam, open(eggs) as f_eggs:
    # do something
```

Comment: how would u do it in Python 3?

Comment: `with open(spam) as f_spam, open(eggs) as f_eggs:`..................
See the fourth bullet point down at http://docs.python.org/release/3.1/whatsnew/3.1.html#other-language-changes

Comment: Yes, Thankyou this is what i have been looking for

Answer (score 3):

```
with open(spam,'r') as f_spam:
  with open(eggs,'r') as f_bar:
    #do stuff with each
```