# Python: multiple file open at once

Tags: python-2.6

I am using python 2.6.6
python

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37)
```

Below is the script.py file, I am getting issue when open 2 file in once.

```
import os
path = '/home/test/testData/log/'
os.chdir(path)

k = 0
word = 'Log ends'
filename1 = 'test.log'
filename2 = 'tes2.log'
with open(filename1) as firstFile, open(filename2) as secondFile:
    for line in firstFile:
        if word in line:
            print(line)
```

When i run the script getting error

python script.py

```
  File "script.py", line 11
    with open(filename1) as firstFile, open(filename2) as secondFile:
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need `nested()` for python 2.6. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847939/with-statement-in-python-with-multiple-files-to-handle)

Comment: Thanks @EdwinvanMierlo it works.